# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError in flask upon trying to sign up

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am following the flask mega tutorial by miguel grinberg. But, after finishing coding the sign up, login and user profiles, when I tried to test it, I get an error trying to sign up:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: user.about_me
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password_hash AS user_password_hash, user.about_me AS user_about_me, user.last_seen AS user_last_seen 
FROM user 
WHERE user.username = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('samyak', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Here is my `register.html` template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.email.label }}<br>
            {{ form.email(size=64) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password2.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password2(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my `register` function:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

And, because this is an `sqlalchemy` error, here is my `User` model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def avatar(self, size):
        digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        return 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?d=identicon&s={}'.format(
            digest, size)
```

I have just started learning flask. Can someone please help me out?

EDIT:
I solved this problem.

1. First, I deleted my database file and my migrations folder.
2. Then, I reinitialized the database with `flask db init`.
3. Then, I ran the following commands:

   flask db migrate -m "database"

   flask db upgrade

Then when I ran the application, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It my limited experience, the database you’re actively working with is now different from the one you have created before hand. If you can, for learning purposes, delete the database file and re-run.